# no design view in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, swing

I'm working on a group project with Github and Eclipse.  My partner has done a lot of work on a GUI and put his work on Github and then I have imported his work through eclipse.  For some reason I can not open a design view at all, theres no buttons down the bottom to switch between design and source, trying to open in windowbuilder editor just opens up the code, running the project just says "Unable to Launch, the selection can not be launched".  I know I have everything installed properly because I made a test project with a GUI and it has everything above working fine.  We both have same versions of everything so I'm really just not sure what to do beyond manually restarting it on my end and copying and pasting code to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it to work.

I was importing it directly through eclipse > GIT > Clone.  and it wasnt working.  but for whatever reason when I cloned it through git onto my desktop and then imported it that way through eclipse, Import > General > Projects from folder.  it worked fine.

Comment: Yes, clone does not automatically import. A repository could have dozens of projects, and you often don't want to import them all.

Comment: @nitind ahh, thank you for the explanation :) at least now it makes sense to me why it was not working!

Answer (score 0):

You can try: `Right click in class -> Open With -> Select your design view editor`